# requests-HTML Enconding error

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, character-encoding, python-requests-html

Hello guys,

When I run this code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'http://www.spell.org.br/documentos/resultadobusca/?eou%5B%5D=&tipo_busca=simples&campo%5B%5D=RESUMO&texto%5B%5D='\
  + parsekeyword(keyword) +\
  '&eou%5B%5D=E&campo%5B%5D=TITULO&texto%5B%5D=&eou%5B%5D=E&campo%5B%5D=TITULO&texto%5B%5D=&mes_inicio=&ano_inicio=&mes_fim=&ano_fim=&qtd_reg_pagina=20&pagina=2'

session = HTMLSession()
link = session.get(url)

linkslist = list(link.html.absolute_links)
```

I get this error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 91835: invalid continuation byte
```

I think it's because of non utf-8 characters in some links.

Since it's happening inside the method, is there a way to handle this?

I'm a begginer, I'm sorry if I missed something obvious.

Comment: try to decode it using `latin-1` encoding

Comment: I don't know how to change it inside the method 'absolute_links'. And I couldn't find something that helps me in the doc...

Answer (score 1):

in python3 and requests, you can use `response.content.decode('utf-8')`, the `response` variable mean is your `link` variable

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But my problem is inside the absolute_links method, the link gets UTF-8 from the header, absolute_links get all links contained in the link page using the same enconding, but some URLs are coming in another encoding, I guess.

Comment: @JonesSabino yes，the http header‘s encoding declaration sometimes is not real response encoding

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I ran the following command and it solved the problem.

```
pip uninstall requests-html
pip install requests-html
```